# Salesforce Attachments in heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

I am new to heroku ,I can see heroku connect supports Attachment object ,but is it possible to store Salesforce Attachments in Heroku?

Answer (score 2):

In general, Heroku Connect doesn't support binary data. From the [FAQ](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect-faq#can-heroku-connect-sync-images-from-salesforce):

> **Can Heroku Connect sync images from Salesforce?**
>
> Heroku Connect [does not currently support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-connect#base64-binary-fields) images or other types of binary data. An alternative approach is to store images in [Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) and sync a simple text field containing a URI for the image between Salesforce and your database.